# Properties of direct sum of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it correct that
$⊕^i (A⊕B)=(⊕^i A)⊕(⊕^i B)$, where $⊕^i$ is a direct sum over an indexed set I.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Write down the isomorphism $(A\oplus B)\oplus(A\oplus B)\cong(A\oplus A)\oplus(B\oplus B)$. Generalize.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A\oplus B=B\oplus A$ and $A\oplus (B\oplus C)=(A\oplus B)\oplus C$. Thus, $\bigoplus_i(A\oplus B)=(\bigoplus_iA)\oplus(\bigoplus_iB)$ for finite index set $I$.

Comment: You need associativity too. And using binary commutativity and ternary associativity can only prove the theorem for finite index sets.

Comment: @Hurkyl The OP has not specified whether $I$ is finite or infinite. Of course, you're correct, though.

Comment: I is any indexed set. It is not necessarily finite.